# How to update array used for data in custom cells for UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to update my array after a user edits a text field in a custom cell in a UITableViewController but not sure how to approach it. Right now how the process works is that when the table view first loads, it makes a call to Firebase and gets all of the data and displays it in a table view.

Data[image: Data]

[image: App]

I have the data stored in a `[[String:Any]]` and I iterate through it when placing the data in their respective cells. It is 2 custom cells, where 1 has a text field and the other has a text field and image view. When I allow the user to edit the notes section of either cell I don't know how to update the data. I have tried, possibly implementing the solution incorrectly, making the text field a delegate and calling `textFieldDidEndEditing` but it didn't work. I am not sure how to approach or how to fix my issue.

This is what I have so far on when toggling edit mode for the table view

```
var tableData = [[String:Any]]()
@IBAction func editTable(_ sender: UIButton) {
        tableView.setEditing(!tableView.isEditing, animated: true)
        if tableView.isEditing {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
        if !tableView.isEditing {

             guard let userID = userData?.userID, let selectedCity = userData?.currentCitySelection, let section = currentSectionString else { return }
            let deleteInfo = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Cities").child(selectedCity).child(section)
            deleteInfo.removeValue()
            let count = tableData.count
            for idx in 0...count - 1 {
                let idxString = String(idx)
                let firebaseDB = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Cities").child(selectedCity).child(section).child(idxString)
                let values = tableData[idx]
                firebaseDB.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { ( err, ref) in
                    if err != nil {
                        print(err)
                        return
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let imageCheck = tableData[indexPath.row]["Image"] {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imageNotesData", for: indexPath) as! ImageNotesCell
            cell.notes.text = tableData[indexPath.row]["Notes"] as! String
            guard let imageFirebasePath = tableData[indexPath.row]["Image"] else {
                return cell }
            let pathReference = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: imageFirebasePath as! String)
            pathReference.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1614 * 1614) { data, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                } else {
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    cell.storedImage.image = image
                }
            }
            return cell
        }
        else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "notesData", for: indexPath) as! NotesCell
            let noteString = tableData[indexPath.row]["Notes"] as! String
            cell.notes.text = tableData[indexPath.row]["Notes"] as! String
            if tableView.isEditing {
                cell.notes.isEditable = true
            } else {
                cell.notes.isEditable = false
            }
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to put cell.notes.delegate = self; cell.notes.tag = indexPath.row, and then implement some delegate method(func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)) to get the text, and save it in your array by the index you pass it as a tag

Comment: @chawki I get an error for calling `cell.notes.delegate = self` saying `Cannot assign value of type 'ReturingUserCityDetailTableViewController' to type 'UITextViewDelegate?'` and which I change it to ` self as! UITextViewDelegate` I get an error saying I can't cast it as that